# Why $L(x,u,p)=\sqrt{\frac{1+p^2}{u}}$ does not depend on $x$, even when $u=u(x)$?

Tags: functions, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm reading an article which writes that a Lagrangian:

$L(x,u,p)=\sqrt{\frac{1+p^2}{u}}$ does not depend on $x$, even when $u$ is function of $x$.

So how does it not depend on $x$? Is it some increase in abstraction (thinking that it could work for any kind of similar $u$ so the specific nature of $x$ doesn't matter)?

http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/ln_/cv.pdf, p. 15-16.

Comment: If $L$ is dependent on $u$ which is dependent on $x$ then $L$ must be dependent on $x$ surely?

Comment: They are simply making the remark that $L(x,u,p)=\ell(u,p)$ for some given function $\ell$.

Comment: @Did So it's an increase in abstraction? That for that result the $x$ doesn't matter.

Comment: "So it's an increase in abstraction?" Yeah, I tried to avoid this one... because **what do you mean by an increase in abstraction** here?

Comment: @Did That one formulates the result by thinking that "this will work for any $u,p$, regardless of what the $x$ inside $u(x)$ does". So $u$ is an abstraction on $u(x)$ where one doesn't consider $x$ or $u(x)$, but only $u$ as a function.

Comment: By the way, one sees were you go astray, simply looking at your title: no, it is not true that $$L(x,u,p)=\sqrt{\frac{1+p^2}{u(x)}}$$ Either one notes that $$L(x,u(x),p)=\sqrt{\frac{1+p^2}{u(x)}}$$ but this is unrelated to the remark made by your authors, or one notes that $$L(x,u,p)=\sqrt{\frac{1+p^2}u}$$ and then the mystery disappears.

Comment: ?? "This" will work (say, in the one dimensional case) for every argument in $\mathbb R^3$, that is, for every real $(w,y,z)$ with $y>0$, $$L(w,y,z)=\sqrt{\frac{1+z^2}y}$$

Answer (score 0):

Formally, your Lagrangian does not depend on $x$. It is only by solving the variational problem  that you get the dependence of $u$ on $x$ required to minimize the action along all possible trajectories $u(x)$.